# Failed tx on simple calling method open nonce 0x4577 caliper logs

Tags: blockchain, ether

I tries try to run caliper on simple contract
first I create besu network quickstart then open that network in metamask
I download the caliper benchmark project and add config.json file

> > config file

```
{
    "caliper": {
        "blockchain": "ethereum",
        "command": {
            "start": "docker-compose -f ./networks/besu/1node-clique/docker-compose.yml up -d && sleep 60",
            "end": "docker-compose -f ./networks/besu/1node-clique/docker-compose.yml down"
        }
    },
    "ethereum": {
        "url": "ws://localhost:8546",
        "contractDeployerAddress": <deployeraddress>,
        "contractDeployerAddressPrivateKey": <deployeraddressprivatekey>,
        "fromAddress": "0x8D80610C20f9A16f23Ff20f29536Ff83B4592a00",
        "fromAddressPrivateKey": "0x2742ff5c9dc8ba995c376591b3383a81cd384c297d8e9e8cbff4fdbc5e6db043",
        "transactionConfirmationBlocks": 12,
        "contracts": {
            "simple": {
                "address": "0xFfC1C198430f5fE0F82548c56bfAC32D15DbC56e",
                "gas": {
                    "open": 45000,
                    "query": 100000,
                    "transfer": 70000
                },
                "abi": [
                    {
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "acc_id",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "int256",
                                "name": "amount",
                                "type": "int256"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "open",
                        "outputs": [],
                        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                        "type": "function"
                    },
                    {
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "acc_id",
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "query",
                        "outputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "int256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "int256"
                            }
                        ],
                        "stateMutability": "view",
                        "type": "function"
                    },
                    {
                        "inputs": [
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "acc_from",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "acc_to",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "internalType": "int256",
                                "name": "amount",
                                "type": "int256"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "transfer",
                        "outputs": [],
                        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                        "type": "function"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then I deploy the simple contract using metamask provider
with the account mentioned in config file
the query function working fine in caliper but the open and transfer give errors

```
Failed tx on simple calling method open nonce 0x4577
2023.07.18-17:50:58.122 error [caliper] [ethereum-connector]    Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xce3b4fcee3c27efda2be92bef6e9a7fd2622c708cec7ad4df097841fa0350b46",
  "blockNumber": 1203,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 1710000,
  "from": <deployeraddress>,
  "gasUsed": 45000,
  "isPrivacyMarkerTransaction": false,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x3765fd39f3d68695b2549f1129fbc85241b5ff3c",
  "transactionHash": "0x157b47b1115b8b68a1a76c667b07a2f0406fae67c389ae251ae5007a765c7209",
  "transactionIndex": 37,
  "type": "0x0",
  "events": {}
}
```

what should I do to solve this isssue?